# Search for closest index in 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array and I am looking for a way to search from one specific point in that array for the nearest field that contains a specific number.

Imagine each `int` in that array is a shelf that contains books. I start a shelf 19 and I am looking for book x that is in shelf 6, 23 and 38. My code should determine which shelf I should go (closest).

Edit: Imagine this 2D array like a chess game and you can move like the king (horizontally, vertically and diagonally).

I want to find the closest way from one field to another one.

```java
int [][] areasE1 = { 
    {1,  2,  3,  4,   5,  6, 7,  8}, 
    {9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16},           
    {17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 ,23, 24},   
    {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32},   
    {33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40},                       
};
```

Comment: Welcome. It would help if you added to this question a bit. Which language are you writing in? What have you tried and why didn't it work? What does "closest" mean here; could you give more detail about your example by explaining which of 6, 23 or 38 would be correct and why?

Comment: Oh i am sorry . This is my first post. I am programming in Java.

Comment: Imagine this Array to be like a chessboard and you can move like the king. So to get from 19 to 6 i need minimum 3 moves.

Comment: I take it that the distance between the two shelves is based on being allowed to move horizontally or vertically, but not diagonally, then?

Comment: Is your array always going to look like this (with the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4... from top-to-bottom, left-to-right) or is this just an example? Could it have any random data in it?

Comment: diagonally is allowed i edited my post so its clear that you can move like the king in a chessgame

Comment: the numbers are only for visualization. it actually contains ids for a database with the books, but thats not relevant